# Gsuit : API to access drive of all users by SuperAdmin Token

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer, google-workspace

I need to access google drive of all the user by admin account token using **Gsuit** API.

Using `Google Apps Admin SDK` [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) I can access information of all account but unable to access their Drive.

I have seen admin can access google drive of all the users by admin console UI,but unable to find  API for same. I can access google drive from individuals access token with this [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) ,but not of all users by admin token,can any one please help me into this.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you should use google service accounts for domain wide delgation of authority.

Please follow the link -- 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount